# How does docker-tcp.socket actually enable Docker's remote API on CoreOS?

Tags: systemd, docker

I'm reading through the systemd configurations for Docker on CoreOS trying to figure out how the TCP port for Docker (port 2375) gets enabled. When I look at the docker.service configuration file, I get the impression Docker is only listening on a file descriptor (`--host=fd://`).

```
# /usr/lib64/systemd/system/docker.service

[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=http://docs.docker.io
Requires=docker.socket
After=docker.socket

[Service]
Environment="TMPDIR=/var/tmp/"
ExecStartPre=/bin/mount --make-rprivate /
Environment=DOCKER_OPTS='--insecure-registry="0.0.0.0/0"'
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
# Run docker but don't have docker automatically restart
# containers. This is a job for systemd and unit files.
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker --daemon --storage-driver=btrfs --host=fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, when I check the listening ports via `netstat`, I see the following:

```
# sudo netstat -apn

Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name 
tcp6       0      0 :::2375                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd        
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1841     1/systemd            /var/run/docker.sock
```

So I dug a little deeper and found a systemd socket config file for Docker:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/docker-tcp.socket

[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API

[Socket]
ListenStream=2375
Service=docker.service
BindIPv6Only=both

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

This seems to be what's providing the listening service at port 2375 (the default Docker port), because when I stop it (using `systemctl stop docker-tcp.socket`) and restart the Docker service (using `systemctl restart docker.service`), port 2375 no longer shows up in `netstat`.

So, my question is this... does the `docker-tcp.socket` config actually enable the local TCP interface as a `--host` option to Docker, or does Docker by default listen on the local TCP interface when `fd://` is specified a a `--host` option, or is the `docker-tcp.socket` config somehow setting up a mapping from `0.0.0.0:2375` to `/var/run/docker.sock` at the OS level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If docker-tcp.socket is started, systemd will listen on tcp port 2375. If it receive a connection, it will start docker via docker.service and pass the file descriptor of this tcp socket to the docker daemon. This way docker will only respond to tcp sockets and never to requests on the unix socket `/var/run/docker.sock`